# Problem on thermal conductivity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, conductors, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I'm an highschooler who's very intrested in physics. I've stumbled on a problem on my textbook  ("Dalla mela di Newton al bosone di Higgs volume III", or translated "From Newton's apple to Higgs' boson volume III" by Ugo Amaldi) about thermal conductivity; the book is in italian since I'm an italian student, thus I'm going to try to translate the text in the most rigorous way I can:

> Two identical bars, one made of copper and the other made of aluminium,
> are aligned in parallel such that the starting point of the first one
> matches the one of the second.

Thus they are tangent and they have in common just a segment of length $d$, which is the common length of the two bars. The requests are:

> -> How is it possible to calculate the system's thermal conductivity constant $\lambda$? 
> -> What is the value of $\lambda$? 
> -> Suppose that the $\lambda$ coefficient has to be less than $500 W m^{-1} k ^{-1}$. Which material has the aluminium to be switched with?$ 
> [Suggestion: the temperature difference is equal for each one of the
> two bars]

**Edit**:
Original version of the problem (not translated)

> Due barre identiche una di rame e una di alluminio, vengono poste come nella figura.
> Come si ricava la formula per il coefficiente $\lambda$ di conducibilità termica?
> Quanto vale $\lambda$?
> Si vuole avere una conducibilitàtermica minore di $500 W/(m K)$. Quale materiale bisogna inserire al posto dell'alluminio?

My reasoning is the following: during the process of heat propagation, the two bars will interact thermodinamically exchanging heat, thus it should be possible to write the following heat balance equation:

$Q_{Cu} + Q_{Al} = Q_{tot}$

From which applying the formula for heat conduction in a stationary system:

${Q \over \Delta t} = \lambda S {\Delta T \over d}$

where $\Delta t$ is the time interval, $\Delta T$ is the temperature difference, $d$ is the thickness of the bar, in this case it corresponds to its length, $S$ is the section which the heat flows into, and $\lambda$ is the thermal conductivity coefficient. Sobstituting into the heat balance equation:

$\lambda_{Cu} S {\Delta T \over d} + \lambda_{Al} S {\Delta T \over d} = \lambda_{tot} S' {\Delta T \over d}$

where $S'$ is the section of the system of the two bars, thus equal to $2S$. The expression above leads to:

$\lambda_{tot} = {\lambda_{Cu} + \lambda_{Al} \over 2}$

which is not correct since plugging the values for $\lambda_{Cu}$ and $\lambda_{Al}$ results in a total conductivity constant of $320 W m^{-1} k ^{-1}$ whereas the result of the book gives me $640 W m^{-1} k ^{-1}$ as result. The problem is the factor of $1 \over 2$ in the final formula.
This might derive from the fact that I was wrong to consider either the system section $S'$ as $2S$ (but to me this is not the case) or to consider the section through which the heat flows - in the expression for $Q_{Cu}$ and $Q_{Al}$ - as the section of the copper or aluminium bar alone (this could be the error). In either case I can't understand why it is necessary not to consider $S' = 2S$ or to consider $S'$ to be always the section that has to be used. 
I've also pondered the fact that the book could be wrong in its result, but this option seems to be very unlikely since the third question asks me to modify the coefficient based on the result I had obtained in the second one.

Thanks a lot for your time and effort in answering me and excuse my English which still has to be practised.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your English to be excused for. It is certainly better than my Italian!!!

Comment: I concur that the book is wrong.

Comment: @Luke_ Can you show the original question too? Maybe something was lost in translation.

Comment: Sure, I've edited the question and added the original version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check which result make sense. For one thing, you cannot get a conductivity larger than either one of the two conductivities. You may increase the thermal conductance (a proprty of the system) but not the conductivity. And then consider what happens if you put in parllel two bars of the same material, let say aluminum with conductivity about 250 W/(m K). The bar you get is just a thicker bar made from that same material. The conductivity is the same. The total conductivity cannot be the just the sum of the two conductivities. Conductivity is a material property. It does not increase by making a bar from the same material thicker.
So, the 640 W/(m K) does not make sense as it larger than the conductivity of both copper and aluminum. No matter how many bars you put in parallel the effective conductivity will be less than the largest conductivity.
What you can increase is the rate of heat transfer or the overal quantity thermal conductance (inverse of thermal resiatance, $ R_T=\frac{q}{\Delta T} $ where $q=Q/\Delta t $.

Comment: Thanks a lot, It makes much more sense now!

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous as the final cross-sectional area is not given although the third question does give an indication of what the question setter expected.

In your analysis you have made the area of the equivalent bar twice the area of one of the bars which are in parallel.

If the requirement is that the area of the equivalent bar is equal to the area of one of the bars the thermal connectivity of the combination is the sum of the two conductivities which I assume are given as $400$ and $240$?
This requirement then makes the third question sensible as I assume you are given a list of conductivities for different materials and then you have to make the sum of the conductivities less than $500$ by choosing an appropriate material in parallel with the copper.

Comment: As both conductivities are less than 500 W/(m K) the third question does not make sense. You cannot get larger conductivity than 500 with both materials having less than that value. By this "method" we could get any "conductivity", no matter how high, by just putting in parallel a bunch of low conductivity wires.

Comment: @nasu *Suppose that the λ coefficient has to be **less than** $500\,\rm Wm^{−1}K^{−1}$*.  The copper ($400)$ is kept and a material with a conductive less than $100$ is put in parallel with the copper to satisfy the criteria.

Comment: It is less than 500 as it is. With copper and aluminum.

Comment: Even with just copper it is less than 500.

Comment: @nasu I tried to explain that the book answer to the second part wants the thermal conductivity of a single bar of the same dimensions as that of one of the original bars and that gives a thermal conductivity of $640$.  From that you can answer part 3.  I also did point out the the question is ambiguous and using your interpretation of the questions leads to part 3 being nonsense.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But no matter how you combine the bars (same cross section as original or just half each) you cannot increase the thermal conductivity of the combination.

Comment: And the condition "less than 500 W/(m K)" is satisfied by most materials excepting diamond.

Comment: I don’t see the ambiguity you refer to. How do you align two solid metal bars in parallel without one of the lateral dimensions increasing? You seem to suggest that a valid scenario is that the bars are co-located. How?

Comment: @Chemomechanics One of my suggested solutions assumes that the two rods are replaced by one rod of the same dimensions as **one** of the original rods.

Comment: And what would be the composition of that replacement rod? Half copper and half aluminum? You still can't get a thermal conductivity of 640 W/m-K that way. You can't get it by any combination of copper and aluminum.